# I cannot see contents of Constraints in the console

Tags: r, constraints

I have created boxconstraints in R. In `print(boxFrontier)`, I do not get values of Constraints

```
boxSpec=portfolioSpec()
setNFrontierPoints(boxSpec)=25
boxConstraints=c("minw\[1:6\]=1","maxw\[1:6\]=16")
boxConstraints
boxFrontier=portfolioFrontier(data=Final_Ret,spec=boxSpec,constraints=boxConstraints)
print(boxFrontier)
```

In Console the print out appears as below:

```
Title:
MV Portfolio Frontier
Estimator:         covEstimator
Solver:            solveRquadprog
Optimize:          minRisk
Constraints:  
Portfolio Points:  5 of 24

Portfolio Weights:
BHP    CSL    RIO    ALL    WDS    RMD
1  0.2234 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.....
```

I get the output which seems okay. However, I get a blank for Constraints:

When I `print(boxFrontier)`, I get the output which seems okay. However, I get a blank for Constraints:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DF=getSymbols(Symbols=c("BHP","CSL","RIO","ALL","WDS","RMD"),auto.assign = 
T, from="2010-01-01",to="2022-12-31")
    tickers=list(BHP,CSL,RIO,ALL,WDS,RMD)
    DF_1=do.call(merge,tickers)
    Final_DF=DF_1[,str_detect(colnames(DF_1),"Adjusted")]
    Final_DF_Ret=diff(log(Final_DF))
    Final_DF_Ret=na.omit(Final_DF_Ret)
    Final_Ret=timeSeries(Final_DF_Ret)
    Final_Ret=100*Final_Ret
    boxSpec=portfolioSpec()
setNFrontierPoints(boxSpec)=25
boxConstraints=c("minw[1:6]=0.01","maxw[1:6]=0.5")
boxFrontier=portfolioFrontier(data=Final_Ret,spec=boxSpec,constraints=boxConstraints)